# CefSharp CachePath not working in WinForms

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, chromium, cefsharp

Hi there I'm doing a WindowsForms Application in order to navigate to a website using the CefSharp Chromium Browser, but I have a big problem. When I enter the app and log in to my website. Then I close the app and will initialize it on the main page without login. I thought that activating the cefsharp browser cache would be the thing to store it but for me it's not working. Anyone can help me?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public ChromiumWebBrowser chromeBrowser;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        InitializeChromium();
    }

    private void InitializeChromium()
    {
        CefSettings cefSettings = new CefSettings();
        cefSettings.CachePath = "C:\\Users\alexm\\Documents\\cache";
        cefSettings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("persist_session_cookies", "1");
        Cef.Initialize(cefSettings);

        chromeBrowser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("https://venomapps.com", new RequestContext());
        this.Controls.Add(chromeBrowser);

        chromeBrowser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    }

    private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        Cef.Shutdown();
    }
}
```

**Update:**

As @amaitland said the thing that keeps the cache in the minimal example and in mine is this code:

```
                //By default, CefSharp will use an in-memory cache, you need to specify a Cache Folder to persist data
            CachePath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "CefSharp\\Cache")
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have you tested with a different website? You can use https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample for testing purposes

Comment: It's not working with any website at least I've tried like 5 login websites.

Comment: Have you tested with the minimum example?  See also https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Questions-&-Support#when-asking-a-question-please-include-the-following

Comment: It works with the minimal project example but I don't know what's the difference I don't see the cache option in the example.

Comment: https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample/search?q=CachePath

Comment: Your code is right, Just change cefsharp to old version to fix (v75.1.142 is okay), I think this is a bug of new version

Comment: Browser should be kept up to date to ensure you have the latest security updates. Using older versions is not recommend/supported. There are no known issues regarding CachePath. Make sure you use an absolute path, relative paths no longer work. Make sure the folder is user writable. If you are using a RequestContext make sure to read https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/3111#issuecomment-629713608

Comment: I don't know what the problem was, It just worked in the new version.